# Aligning 2 DIV's next to eachother in google maps info window

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3

Super simple question I am having trouble getting these two div's to align next to each other inside of a google maps info window. I have been working on this issue for quite some time and finally decided to bring it to stack overflow. Can you guys help me with my problem?

```
var template =
'<div class="containter" style="height: 100%; width:300px;">'+
    '<div class="infobox-header" style="margin: 2px; border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6">'+
        '<strong><h4>'+streetAddress+'</h4></strong></div>'+
    '<div class="infobox-content" style="margin: 2px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid">'+
        '<div class="info-lt-content" style="width: 50%; padding: auto;border: 1px solid">'+
            '<img src ='+defaultPic+' height = 100% width = 100%></a>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="info-rt-content" style="width: 50%; padding: auto;border: 1px solid">'+
                'Bed: '+getDB('bedrooms', this.id)+'<br>'+
                'Bed: '+getDB('bathrooms', this.id)+'<br>'+
        '</div>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="infobox-footer" style="margin: 2px; padding: 5px auto auto 5px; border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6">'+
        '<a href = "../property_info/index.php?id='+this.id+'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">View Listing</button></a>'+
    '</div>'+
'</div>';

infoWindow.setContent(template);
infoWindow.open(map, this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has to do with the `border: 1px solid` on each div (50% + 1px + 50% + 1px = 100% + 2px) and maybe because they are display `block`.

Add these styles `box-sizing:border-box;` (allows border to be calculated with the width value) and `display:inline-block;` to your `.info-lt-content` and `info-rt-content` divs and see if you have any success.